# Jenkins, Docker Build Step create image returns NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, docker, nullpointerexception, dockerfile

I try to create a job generating a DockerFile and creating a docker image using it, I have installed the Docker Plugin to have such steps

I have a Build Step which should be creating an image like this [image: docker image creation and pull]

However when I run this job, all is fine until a reach this step, which returns me the folowing error

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.init(DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:64)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.createDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.getDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:68)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Execute Docker command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also tried using shell script and running this line

```
docker build --pull=true -t registry.mywebsite.com:5000/sequoia-$VERSIONBUILD:$BUILD_NUMBER .
```

but it tells me

```
docker not found
```

which means it didn't have Docker, so I need to use the Docker plugin

Is there a problem with my step or is it something with my configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `docker` service running and the docker binary in $PATH on whichever slave (or master) is running this job.

The plugin simply provides a Jenkins build step to invoke docker as a build step and not the docker service and binary itself. You will need to install and set it up separately.

For more information, please refer the "Configuration" section on https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I had to install docker manually in my docker. Thanks